# Print image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, printing

I want to print image with javascript.
So I used this code to open image in new window and print:

```
win = window.open(img.src,"_blank");
win.onload = function() { win.print(); }
```

This works fine with the default image file:

```
<img id="image1" src="myimage.jpg">
```

But when i replace the default image with image data read from disk:

```
var fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
   img.src = event.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(fileElem);
```

And then open new window & print - the image apears fine in the new window, but no print operation is done.
How to make the win.print() to work?

Comment: *t no print operation is done* What does that mean? The print dialog does not appear?

Comment: Yes, not print dialog apears in the second scenario.

Comment: Why use a new window? CSS Print Media, hide everything but an image when the print happens.

Comment: can you post more informaion about win value. where it is called like that.try to provide environment in jsfiddle!

Comment: epascarello thanks, If i want to print full sized big image it would be a problem with my website's layout. But it looks like a solution if I can't do it otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK!

I'v tried this on Chrome and it's work well :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function printImage() {
                var fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem").files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var html  = "<html><head>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body  style ='-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;'>"+
                        "<img src=\"" + event.target.result + "\" onload=\"javascript:window.print();\"/>" +
                        "</body>";
                    var win = window.open("about:blank","_blank");
                    win.document.write(html);

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(fileElem); 
            }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input type="file" id="fileElem"/>
       <button onclick="printImage()">PRINT</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I don't know all of your code, but maybe this could work:

```
var fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
   var win = window.open(event.target.result,"_blank");
   win.onload = function() { win.print(); }
};
reader.readAsDataURL(fileElem);
```

you don't need anymore "img" tag.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this code, but the behavior is the same (I tested with Google Chrome)