# BarCode Printer Not Printing Text After Hosting In IIS In ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, printing, barcode

iam working asp.net c# project,

in that i need to print barcode sticker,

i successfully done that when developement in Visual Studio 2010.

but when i hosted Asp.Net project files in IIS, & try to print BarCode its not print..( i called local hosted IP - 192.168.1.49 )

i took that IP in my system..

i installed Printer drivers in my system,

would i install drivers in hosted system also?..

another problem is No folder / files created in my system when i click print button..
**C:\BarcodePrint**

any idea & suggestions please..

**My Code :**

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string folder = "C:\\BarcodePrint";
            // Checking if folder is exist or not.. If folder does not exist it will create it
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }


            //string filepath = Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt");
            string filepath = "C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt";
            // Checking if file is exist or not.. If file does not exist it will create it & Truncate it
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                File.Create(filepath).Dispose();
            }


            // Creating a batch file to execute a command a directly to print a barcode
            //string batchfile = Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.BAT");
            string batchfile = "C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.BAT";
            if (!File.Exists(batchfile))
            {
                File.Create(batchfile).Dispose();
            }

            string Description, Catalogue, MfgDate, PartNo, Qty, MRP, Printer;

            Description = txtItemName.Text.Trim().Substring(0, 30);
            MfgDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Catalogue = txtCatalogue.Text.Trim();
            Qty = txtQty.Text.Trim();
            MRP = txtMRP.Text.Trim();

            Printer = "ZDesigner LP 2844";

            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                File.Create(filepath).Dispose();
            }

            // writing data for barcode into the StockBarcode.prn file
            // Location on barcode to print the values :--> A215,25,0,4,2,1,N,AnyValue
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("18,A,001");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine("Q280,024");
                sw.WriteLine("q831");
                sw.WriteLine("rN");
                sw.WriteLine("S2");
                sw.WriteLine("D11");
                sw.WriteLine("ZT");
                sw.WriteLine("JF");
                sw.WriteLine("O");
                sw.WriteLine("R96,0");
                sw.WriteLine("f100");
                sw.WriteLine("N");
                sw.WriteLine("A619,257,2,3,1,1,N," + "\"Description:" + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A437,257,2,3,1,1,N," + "\"" + Description + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A619,232,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"Mfg.Date:" + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A477,234,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"" + MfgDate + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A619,205,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"PartNo:" + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A503,204,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"" + Catalogue + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A619,177,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"Qty:" + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A542,177,2,2,1,1,N," + "\"" + Qty + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A619,149,2,3,1,1,N," + "\"MRP TN: Rs." + "\"");
                sw.WriteLine("A455,150,2,3,1,1,N," + "\"" + MRP + "\"");

                //barcode text
                sw.WriteLine("B330,200,2,3,1,6,50,N," + "\"" + Catalogue + "\"");

                // P1 is used to print the barcode for one time.. If you want to the print the barcode for 10 times use P10
                //sw.WriteLine("P1");
                sw.WriteLine("P" + txtCopys.Text.Trim());
                sw.Close();
            }

            //if (!File.Exists(batchfile))
            if (File.Exists(batchfile))
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(batchfile);
                File.Create(batchfile).Dispose();
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fi.Open(FileMode.Truncate)))
                {
                    // Writing a command to the file
                    //sw.WriteLine("COPY " + Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt prn"));
                    sw.WriteLine("COPY C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt prn");
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }

            if (!File.Exists(batchfile))
            {
                //System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt"), Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.prn"));
                System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt", "C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.prn");
            }
            else
            {
                //System.IO.File.Copy(Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt"), Server.MapPath("~\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.prn"), true);
                System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.txt", "C:\\BarcodePrint\\barcodeprint.prn", true);
            }
            // Executing a command from batch file
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batchfile);

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + batchfile;
            myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            //myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
            myProcess.Start();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            //ExitCode = myProcess.ExitCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //PopMsg.Pop(ex.Message.ToString(), BmGate.WebFormUserControls.Common.MessageBox.IconError, "Error");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385394/print-barcode-from-client-side-using-asp-net