# How I can print the image when click the image link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

```
 <div class="grid col-220 cert">
   <a href="images/1.jpg" class="certTop" rel="prettyPhoto[certificates]"><img src="images/thumb/" /></a>
   <a href="images/1.jpg" class="certBottom" ><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Certificate Name </a>
</div>
```

I want to print 1.jpg when click to the class ".certBottom". How I can do it with?

Comment: Isn't what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612870/print-image-with-javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".certTop").click(function () {
      $(this).append('<img src="images/1.jpg">');
   });
});
```